# how to stop kendo UI NumericTextBoxFor rounding up decimal numbers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to allow our task scheduler to accept time estimations of half a day. unfortunately, when the user enters 0.5 and clicks save the program rounds up any decimal number to the nearest whole number. I am using Kendo UI NumericTextBoxFor.

I have tried adding some jquery that ought to format the entered decimal correctly. I have also tried adding .Decimal(5) to the end of the razor statement. I can't find any other javascript that might be influencing this anywhere else in the program.

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleViewModel.TimeRemaining, new { @class = "control-label" })
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk mandatoryred" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                    @Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.ScheduleViewModel.TimeRemaining).Decimals(5)
                    <div>
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleViewModel.TimeRemaining, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<script>
 $("#initial").width('400').kendoNumericTextBox({
    //format: '#.####################',
    format: 'n3',
    decimals: 4
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");

function handleAssignAndScheduleSuccess(result) {
    if (result.responseJSON) {
        // The controller action returned a JSON object with the redirectTo property
        // let's redirect to this location:
        window.location.href = result.responseJSON.redirectTo;
    }

    if (result.redirectTo) {
        // The controller action returned a JSON object with the redirectTo property
        // let's redirect to this location:
        window.location.href = result.redirectTo;
    } else {
        // The controller action returned a partial view with the form and the errors
        // So we need to update some containing DIV with it:

        $('#assignAndScheduleRequestFormDiv').html(result);
    }
}
function handleAssignAndScheduleFailure(result) {

    $('#errorAssignAndScheduleRequestDiv').html(result.responseText);

}
</script>
```

Comment: From their site.`"Rounding of Numbers"

The widget controls the precision of the entered number using the half-up rounding technique. To disable this functionality, use the round configuration option. Once you turn off the rounding, the value is truncated up to the desired precision length without rounding it` So maybe try to add `round: false` when you create the control?

Comment: Did you tried setting `.Round(false)` ? It's is `true` by default: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/numerictextbox/configuration/round

Comment: Hi, I think you have pass wrong control Id in script tag. Please try with below code `$("#ScheduleViewModel_TimeRemaining").width('400').kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: 'n3',
    decimals: 4,round: false
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");`

Comment: I have tried setting round to false it doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Hitesh Gohel - I have tried your code and although it interacts with the element it doesn't make any difference to the rounding problem